# Basic user redirection based on credentials used

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm setting up a plain HTML/PHP(to perform `include()`) website for demo purposes strictly. I'd like to make a *functional login page* that redirects the user based on the credentials used.

For example: If the user/pass combination used was "editor" and "123456" respectively, then he will be redirected to `/editor.html`. The same for "admin" and "user" members...

Certainly I already have the basic login layout in HTML, but how can I make it functional that way? How could I achieve this effectively?

Thank you very much for your time,
Regards

Html code

```
<div id="pane-login" class="panel-body active">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="inputer">
          <div class="input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--.form-group-->

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="inputer">
          <div class="input-wrapper">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Pass">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--.form-group-->

      <div class="form-buttons clearfix">
        <label class="pull-left">
          <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1">
          Remember</label>
        <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='index.php';" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Enter</button>
      </div>
      <!--.form-buttons-->
    </div>
```

Comment: Please Post your html code here

Comment: Hi there. Just did ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so first of all, your form isn't actually a form here.

Prepend to the inputs:

```
 <form name="formname" method="POST" action="yourphpfile.php">
```

and end with a

```
 </form>
```

Add a "name" value to each of the inputs
Remove the onClick from your submit Button.

In your php file, do the following:

```
$username = $_POST["firstinputname"]
$password = $_POST["password"]
```

Evaluate the login info and do a switch case in case login is correct;

```
switch($username)
{
    case "editor":
          header('Location: /yourlocation.php');
          break;

    case "another":
          header('Location: /anotherlocation.php');
          break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ralph, it worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You make the form using HTML, then in PHP you use the $_POST like this for example :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    if($_POST['username'] == "editor" && $_POST['password'] == "123456")
    {
        header('Location: /editor.html');
    }
}
?>
```

to make it dynamic you can use mysql ( type "login php + mysql" in google )